# Python Boto EC2 find instance given its IP address

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

Using boto in Python, how can I find the boto.ec2 instance object given an IP address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Digging through the [boto documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2.connection), I found the `get_only_instances` method, which you use to get all instances. You can pass a filter dictionary to it, to filter by IP Address (I found this in the [EC2 API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html) under the **Filter.N** title).

So for example, to get the instance with IP `1.1.1.1`, you would do:

```
filters = {"ip-address": "1.1.1.1"}
result_list = conn.get_only_instances(filters=filters)
```

Then `result_list[0]` should be the Instance object for the instance with that IP address.

Comment: filters = {"private_ip_address": "10.122.44.2"} in case you are in a vpc

Comment: This was a huge help to me. Just added `only_running_filter = {"instance-state-name": "running"}` filter to ease our transition between two classes of servers.

Comment: this seems only to work for boto2.  using boto3, im not able to locate this functionality.  Im simply trying to get an instance id by ip, when its stopped state.  Thought this was possible, but getting empty list results for the ip using describe_instances with private-ip-address filter when stopped.

Answer (score 7):

### boto3

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

filters = [{
    'Name': 'ip-address', 
    'Values': ['1.1.1.1'],
}]
result_list = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=filters)
```

Comment: You couldn't think of anything to say, or any documentation to link to, or *anything* besides the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using boto3 then you can try the following code to get the instance id

```
import boto3
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

private_ip = 'xxx.xx.xx.xxx'
response = ec2_client.describe_instances(
        Filters=[{
            'Name': 'network-interface.addresses.private-ip-address',
            'Values': [private_ip]
        }]
    )
instance_id = response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
print(instance_id)
```